# Automatic Docker Hub builds from GitLAB, not github

Tags: docker, git, gitlab

As per title. I would like to configure automated builds on Docker Hub, [as specified here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#prerequisites).

My build context (the build context is a repository containing a Dockerfile) is hosted in GitLAB.

Comment: FWIW, the `Docker Hub` section of the docs you pointed to is listed in the `Superseded products and tools` section (on the leftside navbar), is it wise trying to build a *new* solution based on it?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @DanCornilescu Thanks for the heads-up. I'm confused now as to what is the official way of automatically building and publishing an image from a public github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature [is not supported](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/334) as the issue in the link says.

They promised it for late 2016 but now at 2017 the issue is still open.

One comment was to look for [gitlab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/), which might be my best guess of workaround  for now, waiting the Docker Hub version to come.

Comment: Yes there seems to be a way to push into a private registry hosted in gitlab itself. That looks neat.